# RegionPlot3D and point plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

Suppose to have the set of inequalities

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
2x+3y+z\leq5,\\
4x+y+2z\leq11,\\
3x+4y+2z\leq8,\\
x\geq0,\\
y\geq0,\\
z\geq0,\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
and suppose that you want to show the RegionPlot3D associated to it together with the point $(0,0,0)$ (maybe by highlighting the point somehow).

How can you do it?

One last thing: suppose to have multiple points, say (0,0,0), (2.5,0,0), and (2,0,1) and that you want to make a sort of path (0,0,0)-> (2.5,0,0) -> (2,0,1) on the region, how can you do it?

Comment: Maybe I will use `Sphere` to plot the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `HalfSpace[{2, 3, 1}, 5]` to describe `2 x + 3 y + z <= 5` etc.

```
reg = RegionIntersection[HalfSpace[{2, 3, 1}, 5], 
   HalfSpace[{4, 1, 2}, 11], HalfSpace[{3, 4, 2}, 8], 
   HalfSpace[-{1, 0, 0}, 0], HalfSpace[-{0, 1, 0}, 0], 
   HalfSpace[-{0, 0, 1}, 0]];
Show[Region[Style[reg, Directive[Opacity[.8], Orange]]], 
 Region[Style[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {2.5, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}}], 
   Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[5]]]], 
 Region[Style[Ball[{{0, 0, 0}, {2.5, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}}, .08], 
   Darker@Cyan]], Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Add points with [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) and combine graphics with [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[
  2 x + 3 y + z <= 5 && 4 x + y + 2 z <= 11 && 
   3 x + 4 y + 2 z <= 8 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0,
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 5}],
 Graphics3D[
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{0, 0, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For multiple points

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   2 x + 3 y + z <= 5 && 4 x + y + 2 z <= 11 &&
    3 x + 4 y + 2 z <= 8 && 
    x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0,
   {x, y, z}];

SeedRandom[1234];

Show[
 RegionPlot3D[rgn[[1]],
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]],
 Graphics3D[
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[RandomPoint[rgn, 5]]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** so I missed the last three conditions

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[{2 x + 3 y + z <= 5 && 4 x + y + 2 z <= 11 && 
    3 x + 4 y + 2 z <= 8 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {x, -1, 
   2}, {y, -1, 2}, {z, -1, 2}
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.1]]
  , Mesh -> 5
  ],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.3]}]
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

For additional points making a path:

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {2.5, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}};
```

and add to `Graphics`:

```
, Sphere[#, 0.05] & /@ pts
, Thickness[0.02], Line@pts
```

---

**original answer**

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[{2 x + 3 y + z <= 5 && 4 x + y + 2 z <= 11 && 
    3 x + 4 y + 2 z <= 8}, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, {z, -1, 3}
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.1]]
  , Mesh -> 5
  ],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.3]}]
 ]
```

[image]